# How can I abort Mojave installation?

Tags: macos, install, mojave

I am on Sierra now, and the appstore has downloaded the Mojave Installer, however I quit it without going though any of the steps, the installer is just sitting in my apps folder.

I would like to cancel the Mojave installation and remove the downloaded files, is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already canceled it by quitting the installer, just delete the  installer if you do not ever want to upgrade, or keep it for a later install.

The **/Applications/Install macOS Mojave.app** can be double-clicked to restart the upgrade, whenever you want.

---

On a side note, if you do not want the **App Store** to do things automatically... then in **System Preferences** > **App Store**, uncheck the appropriate check boxes.

On my system I like to manually control when any upgrading occurs so I set my **App Store** preferences as in the image below.

[image: App Store in System Preferences]

Comment: Thank you!

On that note, would you recommend upgrading to mojave though?

My is Macbook Pro Mid 2012, 8Gb, 1tb HDD
It's on the lower end so I'm a bit concerned. Some people say that Mojave has optimization that makes older Macs perform better, but others say its crap, so I was just wondering.

Comment: @WhiteWashedWall, Please have look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and take the [Tour](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tour) too. -- As to the question in your comment, it is primarily opinion based and therefore I suggest you properly backup your system so it could be restored to the current OS and then test macOS Mojave for yourself. Only you can determine whether or not any change in performance is going to be acceptable or not. If it's not, then restore your system from its proper backup.